# How can I use Zend Studio for Java development?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, zend-studio

I have the Zend Studio, which is a PHP editor based on Eclipse. I want to use it now to develop some Java. I think Zend has disabled all the Java centric project/views/perspectives that come with Eclipse (or may be not included the right plugins?)
What steps should I take to use it, instead of having two Eclipse instances open at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eclipse instead,and add PHP support to it using [eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need it this way, but there is nothing wrong with having more than one instance of Eclipse going. Why waste time getting Zend to take Java (which most likely isn't possible)?

Comment: 1. for the sake of knowing
2. Convenience - less windows are open less chance of doing mistakes

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but since it came high in google searches when I was myself looking for an answer:

It's perfectly possible to use Zend Studio for Java development as well. All you need to do is the following:

1. Select 'Help' -> 'Install New Software...'
2. Click 'Available Software Sites'
3. Enable the existing but disabled 'Eclipse' site matching the Eclipse release your version of Zend Studio is built on
4. Go back to 'Install New Software...' and select 'http://download.eclipse.org/releases/*nameofrelease*'
5. Select & install the Java related support under 'Programming Languages' (Eclipse Java Development Tools)